# Cannot read property '$$phase' of null at Object.$$debounceViewValueCommit

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting this error while moving from one page to another. I have add order page with forms if I go to add order page directly it works fine but if go orders list page and then go to add order page then i got this error and all my forms fields on add order page set touched automatically . what could be the issue please help . thanks in advance [image: error]

here is my home.html code

```
<div class="container body" ng-cloak>
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
        <div class="left_col scroll-view">
            <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                <img src="../assets/images/logo1.PNG" style="width:25%; float:left;"/>
                <a href="index.html" class="site_title" style="float: left;width: 117px;margin-top: 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 17px;"><span>Trackerist</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- menu profile quick info -->
            <div class="profile clearfix padding-2x">
                <h5 class="text-center">Welcome</h5>
                <h5 class="text-center">{{domain | capitalize}}</h5>
            </div>
            <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                <div class="menu_section">
                    <!-- <h3>General</h3> -->
                    <ul class="nav side-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> DASHBOARD </a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-if="is_admin"><a><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> COMPANY <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.inviteCompany">Invite companies</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.listCompany">List companies</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li ng-if="!is_admin">
                            <a><i class="fa fa-book"></i> ORDERS <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.orderAdd">Create Order</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.orderListing">List Orders</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.savedOrders">Saved Orders</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li ng-if="!is_admin">
                            <a><i class="fa fa-user"></i> AGENTS <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.agentAdd">Add Agent</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.agentListing">List Agents</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li ng-if="!is_admin">
                            <a><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> DRIVERS <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.driverAdd">Add Driver</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.driverListing">List Drivers</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.mapView">Live Map View</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li ng-if="!is_admin">
                            <a><i class="fa fa-archive"></i> WAREHOUSES <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.warehouseAdd">Add Warehouse</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="home.warehouseListing">List Warehouses</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- top navigation -->
    <div class="top_nav">
        <div class="nav_menu">
            <nav>
                <div class="nav toggle">
                    <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                </div>


                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="display:flex">
                        <form ng-show="showSearchBar" class="navbar-form" role="search" style="width:80%">
                                <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 10%;" ng-click="showSearchBar=false">
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                                                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>

                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width:10%" ng-click="searchIt()">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                            <li><a href="javascript:;"> Profile </a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <span class="badge bg-red pull-right">50%</span>
                                    <span>Settings</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /top navigation -->

    <!-- page content -->
    <div class="right_col" role="main" ui-view="">

    </div>
    <!-- /page content -->

    <!-- footer content -->
    <footer>
        <div class="pull-right">
          Copyright Trackerist &copy; 2017. All rights reserved.
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /footer content -->
   </div>
    </div>

   <script>

$(document).ready(function () {


    $.getScript('assets/js/custom.js');


  });

 </script>
```

here is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title> Logistics  </title>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">




<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="assets/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="assets/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
<!-- Chart.js -->
<script src="assets/vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- gauge.js -->
<script src="assets/vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-
 progressbar.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="assets/vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<!-- Skycons -->
<script src="assets/vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
<!-- Flot -->
<script src="assets/vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<!-- Flot plugins -->
<script src="assets/vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
<!-- DateJS -->
<script src="assets/vendors/DateJS/build/date.js"></script>
<!-- JQVMap -->
<script src="assets/vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
<script src="assets/vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Switchery -->
<script src="assets/vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NProgress -->
<link href="assets/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="assets/vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-local-storage/src/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css"></script>-->

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
 libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDLy0G_2BB47UWc6NwDCqHsrpaRfx2OyR8"></script>
  <!--<script src="http://jvandemo.github.io/angularjs-google-maps/dist/angularjs-google-maps.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<!--<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>-->
<!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.smartWizard.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/vs-google-autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="factories/subDomian.js"></script>


  </head>


  <body ng-app="logistics" class="{{ bodylayout }}">

<ui-view>

</ui-view>


  </body>



  </html>
```

there are the routes

```
 .state('home.orderAdd', {
  url: "/orders/add",
  controller: "orderController",
  templateUrl: "views/order/add.html",
  resolve: {
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load("controllers/orders.js");
    }]
  },
  authenticate: true
})
.state('home.orderListing', {
  url: "/orders/listing",
  controller: "orderController",
  templateUrl: "views/order/listing.html",
  resolve: {
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load("controllers/orders.js");
    }]
  },
  authenticate: true
})
.state('home.orderDetails', {
  url: "/orders/details?order_id",
  controller: "orderController",
  templateUrl: "views/order/details.html",
  resolve: {
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load({serie: true,
        name: "login",
        files:[
          "controllers/orders.js",
          "node_modules/qrcode-generator/qrcode.js",
          "node_modules/qrcode-generator/qrcode_UTF8.js",
          "node_modules/angular-qrcode/angular-qrcode.js"
        ]
      });
    }]
  },
  authenticate: true
})
.state('home.savedOrders', {
  url: "/orders/savedOrders-listing",
  controller: "orderController",
  templateUrl: "views/order/saved_listing.html",
  resolve: {
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load("controllers/orders.js");
    }]
  },
  authenticate: true
})
.state('home.orderDetail', {
  url: "/orders/details/:order_id",
  controller: "orderController",
  templateUrl: "views/order/add.html",
  params: {
    'order_id': null,
    'order_obj': null,
    'type': 'order-details',
  },
  resolve: {
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load({serie: true,
        name: "login",
        files:[
          "controllers/orders.js",
          "node_modules/qrcode-generator/qrcode.js",
          "node_modules/qrcode-generator/qrcode_UTF8.js",
          "node_modules/angular-qrcode/angular-qrcode.js"
        ]
      });
    }]
  },
  authenticate: true
})
.state('home.orderEdit', {
  url: "/orders/edit?order_id",
  controller: "orderController",
  templateUrl: "views/order/add.html",
  params:{
    'order_id': null,
    'order_obj': null,
    'type': 'order-edit',
  },
  resolve: {
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load("controllers/orders.js");
    }]
  },
  authenticate: true
})
```

here is my versions

```
 "dependencies": {
"angular": "1.6.6",
"angular-animate": "^1.6.6",
"angular-aria": "^1.6.6",
"angular-jwt": "0.1.9",
"angular-loading-bar": "^0.9.0",
"angular-local-storage": "^0.7.1",
"angular-material": "^1.1.5",
"angular-qrcode": "^7.2.0",
"angular-ui-router": "1.0.3",
"nprogress": "^0.2.0",
"oclazyload": "^1.1.0",
"sweetalert": "^2.0.6",
"vsGoogleAutocomplete": "^0.5.0"
 }
```

> cause of error

```
<div class="right_col ng-scope" role="main" ui-view="" data-ng-animate="1">
```

Comment: Just he got a object null, due ??? missed lib or settings, a params or args nulls from somewhere :). updating your angular version `""angular": ">=1.4."," in bower.json` should solve this problem

Comment: I have updated question @MaximShoustin

Comment: my angular version is already 1.6.6 @headmax

Comment: Did you tryed this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-animate.js"></script>` source lib ? if isn't ng-animate the problem ...

Comment: this file not found @headmax tried it in google using this link https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bngular-animate.js

Comment: sorry this cdn you can take https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/ and you can use for a try if you didn't yet https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js

Comment: did you solved your issue?

Comment: It seems that it is an issue with the AngularJS v1.6.0-rc.2. I changed to the newest version and it disappeared.